# Launched a Laravel app but I can just access the Frontpage, no under sites

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, deployment, routes

I have uploaded my Laravel application to a subdirectory in my hosts (no root), so it looks like:

**websites/myapp/index.php**

In "myapp" subdirectory I have all files from the Laravel's PUBLIC folder.

I have a .htaccess located in **websites/myapp/.htaccess** that looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The routing since to be working perfectly. When I hover over a link in the menu I get the right url. For example:

- mydomain.com/about_us
- mydomain.com/contact
- mydomain.com/register
- mydomain.com/login

and so on...

The problem is that I click on those links to go to those pages I get an error stating:

```
    Internal Server Error

    The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

    Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

    More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

    Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
    Apache/2.4.29 Server at gerichtsfest.eu Port 80
```

So, actually I just can access the homepage but not other pages.

I have read tons of .htaccess tutorials, but it just get more messy. I have not idea what to change in the .htaccess so it redirect properly

Any help would be appretiated

Comment: try like this, `mydomain.com/public/about_us`

Comment: @arun is not about changing the routings. Is about there is not access to any other page than the home page regadless which is it.

Comment: `storage\logs\laravel.log` u may check this file for exact error

Comment: @arun There is nothing there. Empty. This is an app that has been just deployed but hasn't started at all since I am not being able to configure the server to find it.